# How to avoid rewriting the same code in different methods

Tags: c#

> OLD Question
>   So this is what I am trying to achieve...
>
> I have an existing abstract class ..lets name it Class1.cs . It
>   contains definitions for a number of methods. So now I have included
>   some new functionality which needs to be implemented in each and every
>   method of the Class1 class. So for ex-
>
> ```
>         public void Method_1(string arg1, string arg2)
>         {
>            /*
>            //some code implementation specific to Method_1
>            */
>            Dictionary<string, object> dict= new Dictionary<string, object>();
>            //there can be more or less arguments in other methods
>            dict.Add("Arg1", arg1);
>            dict.Add("Arg2", arg2);
>            Method_2(dict);
>         }
> ```
>
> I have to do the exact same thing in all the methods but the arguments
>   can vary. So the dictionary object can have "n" parameters . Is there
>   a way that I can avoid the manual labor of adding the same code
>   repeatedly (maybe use a design pattern if possible)
>
> i think i am not clear... bundling up the dictionary generation
>   mechanism is not my concern , I would still need to add the same code
>   in all the methods(around 50) ..I am trying to avoid manually calling
>   the same code again and again 50 times...

**Edited and reframed the question**
I have finally decided that I would build the dictionary in a private method and call that in all the other methods. Kindly ignore everything else before this paragraph.
My methods will look like this

```
public void Method1(string a, string b , string c)
{ 
   Dictionary<string,object> dict = BuildDictionary(new {a, b ,c}); 
   /*the dict object should have the following structure
                           key=a,   value=  value of a 
                           key =b , value = value of b
                           key =b , value = value of b*/
}
public void Method2(string x, string y)
{ 
   Dictionary<string,object> dict = BuildDictionary(new {x,y}); 
   /*the dict object should have the following structure
                           key= x,  value=  value of x 
                           key =y , value = value of y */
}
private Dictionary<string,object> BuildDictionary(params object[] values)
{
   //values.ToString() gives  = { a= "Value of a", b== "Vaue of b", c= "Value of c"}
   //Copy pasting Simon's Code here(use of anonymous objects)
   var dictionary = values.GetType()
                       .GetProperties()
                       .ToDictionary(pi => pi.Name, pi => pi.GetValue(values));
   //this dictionary object gives me a count of 7 with keys as the properties of the object datatype(which is not relevant to my case). 
}
```

So what changes do i need to make to the BuildDictionary method in order to get the desired dictionary structure?

Comment: How are you using the dictionary in Method_2? It might help to change the signature to that method to streamline the process. And are the Keys follow a pattern (ie ArgN) or this was just for demonstration purposes?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of `looping`!

Comment: @SimonBelanger : I have edited the question..... bundling up the dictionary generation mechanism is not my concern , I would still need to add the same code in all the methods(around 50) ..I am trying to avoid manually calling the same code again and again 50 times...

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What are those dictionaries for ? Why are you creating the dictionary in method_1 and passing it to method_2 ? some context so we can help you ????

Comment: What you are asking for is something like Aspect-Oriented Programming (AoP) and that's not a minor thing to bring to a codebase. Think twice about going that route. My suggestion is to move the logic of creating the dictionary in a private method and have one-liners in all implementing method. You'll have to take the hit.

Comment: 50 methods in abstract class is probably more concerning than anything else... There may be some other way of doing whatever you actually doing (you may not need 50+ methods if you doing some proxy generation...)

Comment: I'm thinking it's legacy code base that can't be easily changed (nikhil hinted that the method's signature can't be changed).

Comment: It would really help to see the body of Method_2 and perhaps the methods immediately downstream of Method_2.

Comment: Yes, you are *still* not being clear.  You say you don't want to call "the same code" again and again.  What part of this code exactly are you trying to avoid calling?  Do you mean that you want `Method_2` to be called without actually calling it?  If you're going to call it from 50 places, and everywhere you call it has different inputs, I don't see how you could avoid writing *anything*.  Please be more specific.  Perhaps show an example of what you would *like* to do, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Also - you mentioned that this is in an *abstract* class, but you haven't shown anything so far that couldn't be done in a regular class.  Does being abstract have something to do with your question?  For example, are these other methods in classes that extend your abstract class?

Comment: @MattJohnson : Method_2 here is just for demonstration purposes ..it actually has reference variables as parameters and returns a dictionary object. So I am trying to avoid manually calling the dictionary building mechanism 50 times.. also abstract does not have any importance here...sorry for the confuion

Comment: @MattJohnson : look at it this way...ignore the previous code...assume that I have three private methods in a class which I need to call in all the other 40-50 public methods...is there anyway i can get around this without manually calling them everytime in the public methods?

Comment: In general, no. There is no way to call a method without calling it.  If it's a big block of code, you can put it in it's own method and call that - but you always have to call *something*.  You could look into AOP, but even then you will have to define the aspect and how to apply it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without much information on the nature of Method_2 and what the Keys in the dictionary represents, I'll suggest two options.

**The keys always represent Arg + N**

In this case, the signature of the Method_2 could be a `params`

```
public void Method_2(params object[] values)
{
    var argNo = 0;
    var dictionary = values.ToDictionary(x => "Arg" + ++argNo);
}

public void Method_1(string arg1, string arg2)
{
    // ...
    Method_2(arg1, arg2);
}
```

**The keys represent the caller's method parameters name**

A generic way to do this would be with anonymous object.

```
public void Method_2(object values)
{
    var dictionary = values.GetType()
                           .GetProperties()
                           .ToDictionary(pi => pi.Name, pi => pi.GetValue(values));
}

public void Method_1(string arg1, string arg2)
{
    Method_2(new { arg1, arg2 });
}
```

Edit: If Method_2 cannot be changed either, build the dictionary with a separate method with the same logic as one of the two options.

**Answer to edit**: The reason your implementation is not working is because you are get all the properties on an array of object and not on a (anonymous) object. You didn't copy my code completely. `params object[] values` should be `object values`.

Comment: output of option 2 is not exactly what I am looking for... if arg1 ="a" and agr2="b" , then the login in Method_2 creates the dictionary object which has 7 keys  like length , longlength , Rank...which I guess are the properties of the object data type

Comment: @Simon..  I have edited the question again...kindly have a look at the edited question

Comment: The build dictionary should be an `object`, not `params object[]`. Creating an anonymous type create one object and that will always be the case, unless you try to pass multiple objects with defeats the purpose

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Linq;

...

// add as many elements as you want
var args = new object[] {arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4};

int i = 0;
var dict = args.ToDictionary(x => "Arg" + ++i, x => x);

Method_2(dict);
```

This will work, but I have no idea why you would want to pass in a dictionary to `Method_2` unless you had no other choice.

Comment: I have edited the question..... bundling up the dictionary generation mechanism is not my concern , I would still need to add the same code in all the methods(around 50) ..I am trying to avoid manually calling the same code again and again 50 times

Answer (score 0):

You should use a loop and have a pattern for how you name your variable. In your method2 you should be able to easily finding these args. 
Below, I assume that you have a list of arguments called args, and I add them all to a dictionary. Enjoy

```
public void Method_1(string arg1, string arg2)
{
   /*
   //some code implementation specific to Method_1
   */
   var dict = GetArguments(args);
   Method_2(dict);
}

private Dictionary<string, object> GetArguments(List<string> args)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dict= new Dictionary<string, object>();
   var counter = 1;
   foreach(var argItem in args)
   {
        dict.Add("Arg"+counter++, argItem);
   }
   return dict;
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question..... bundling up the dictionary generation mechanism is not my concern , I would still need to add the same code in all the methods(around 50) ..I am trying to avoid manually calling the same code again and again 50 times

Comment: You could put this dictionary as a class-level field and update the setter of the args list to update this dictionary whenever u add an item. that way you do not need to do any of that iteration. However, be careful to reset this list/dictionary before starting to use if that cause issues for your logic

Answer (score 0):

Create a private method that will construct the dictionary. You could use a simple loop or or something more concise like Matt suggested.

```
public void Method_1(string arg1, string arg2)
{
    var dict = BuildDictionary(arg1, arg2);
    Method_2(dict);
}

private Dictionary<string, object> BuildDictionary(params object[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dict= new Dictionary<string, object>();
    for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        dict.Add("Arg" + i, args[i]);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

With Matt's version:

```
private Dictionary<string, object> BuildDictionary(params object[] args)
{
    return args.ToDictionary(x => "Arg" + ++i, x => x);
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question..... bundling up the dictionary generation mechanism is not my concern , I would still need to add the same code in all the methods(around 50) ..I am trying to avoid manually calling the same code again and again 50 times